# Cocos2d-x AdMob iOS Integration Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, cocos2d-x

Chaps

Finally back to my first game using Cocos2d-x (3.8) and trying to display a banner ad in iOS/xCode.  Struggled with this for several days and read half of the internet.  Apologises if the fix is out there to be found.

What I did….

Added the following frameworks to my project:

iAd,,AdSupport, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, CoreData, CoreGraphics, CoreTelephony, GameController, EventKit, EventKitUI, MediaPlayer, MessageUI, StoreKit, SystemConfiguration

Build Settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode => No

Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags, add  -ObjC

Downloaded the GoogleMobileAds.framework, unzipped to find GoogleMobileAds.framework.

Drag this from Finder into the [Project] -> Frameworks folder.  Select ‘Copy items if needed’.  Also added the Mediation Adapters folder with headers.

Download the iAdAdapter library, unzipped download to find libAdapterIAd.a library.

Drag this from Finder into the [Project] -> Frameworks folder.  Select ‘Copy items if needed’.

[image]

Added the GoogleMobileAds.framework and libAdapterIAd.a to my Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

[image]

The error I see:

[image]

Any fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try using this https://github.com/SonarSystems/Cocos-Helper

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `CoreBluetooth` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add These Two Frameworks :

```
SafariServices
CoreBluetooth
```

[image]